# How to check my item based collaborative filtering algo is correct?

Tags: php, codeigniter, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I have just created an algorithm for item based collaborative filtering, that can take an array of data in the form `[username]=>[item]=>[rating]` and recommend other items based on the current items the user has rated/bought by calculating a prediction of the rating the user will give that item if he were to use it and rate it.

My question is, how do I check the accuracy of my recommendation system?

Comment: Why is this tagged `[php]` and `[ruby]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pick a number of random users and items you actually have the rating for and try to predict the rating using your algorithm. Calculate the [RMSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square_deviation) between your prediction and the actual rating. The lower the value, the better.

Depending on your algorithm, the fact that you have the rating for the item might introduce a heavy bias to your RMSE. In that case, perform your calculations as if you didn't know the rating (eg: move everything to a separate database and discard the records you are trying to "predict").

Interesting read: [The Netflix Prize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netflix_Prize)

Answer (score 3):

A library like Apache Mahout provides a framework to do this work automatically.

But let me assume you want to code your own solution.

Typically, you test the accuracy using [cross-validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29). So, grab a data set of ratings. Divide it into two sets, one set is the training set, and the other set is the "test set". Usually, this is done by randomly picking, say, 80% of the users and putting them into the training test and using the remaining 20% for the test set.

One by one, pick the users in the test set. To test your accuracy, you can use an all-but-one  metric: hide one rating from this one use, and try to predict it. (Some authors call it [leave-one-out](http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/modules/cross_validation.html) instead of all-but-one.) Use only the training set and the data from this one user (except, of course, for the rating you have hidden). Each time you do this, you will get an error, you can just sum them up and divide by the number of predictions you made. That's the mean average error.

There are other ways to do it, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I like Root Mean Square Error but one other one that may help is called 'Mean Average Precision @ K' AKA 'MAPK'.

The 'Average Precision' part of MAPK is simply the relevancy of the top K recommendations.  So basically, look at what your model predicts as far as recommendations go and see how many of them are 'hits' in the actual resulting set (in this case, the actual resulting set = set of items users supplied a rating for)

This like gives a nice example of what I'm talking about:
http://makarandtapaswi.wordpress.com/2012/07/02/intuition-behind-average-precision-and-map/

Answer (score -2):

Just test in this simple form:

```
USER A - ITEM 1 - 10.0
USER A - ITEM 2 - 10.0
USER A - ITEM 3 - 10.0

USER B - ITEM 1 - 10.0
USER B - ITEM 2 - 10.0
USER B - ITEM 3 - 10.0

USER C - ITEM 1 - 10.0
USER C - ITEM 2 - 10.0
```

now USER C should get a recommendation 10.0 for ITEM 3